# Mongoose: .save is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm very new and I've looked through the archives but just what's going on in this code eludes me. I used express-generator to create a calendar app and now I want to hook it up to MongoDB. The actual connection to Mongo is working, but I can't get it to save a document.

The relevant portion of my **global.js** (where I'm running my front-end Javascript) looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var ev = new Event({ date: "a6_13_2016", time: 900, description:"Fencing"});
    ev.save(function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log("Success!")
    })
```

This is where I'm getting the "TypeError: ev.save is not a function" message. My **models/Events.js** looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: String,
    time: Number,
    description: String
});

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

My **routes/events.js** looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Event = require('../models/Events.js');

/* GET /event listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.find(function (err, dates) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(dates);
  });
});

/*POST event*/
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* GET /event/id */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I want to save something to test it, but it's giving me ".save is not a function. Other than

```
var events = require('./routes/events');
app.use('/events', events);
```

and the code establishing the Mongoose connection my **app.js** file is boilerplate. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: You are running mongoose from front-end?

Comment: [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) is a global that already exists in browsers. Also, not sure why you're using mongoose stuff in the front-end, you will probably just want to send an AJAX request to send data from your client to your server and then just do the mongoose stuff in the server-side.

Answer (score 3):

I see

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Are you trying to use Mongoose in browser?

It's supposed to be used on the server-side.

In browser you need to send AJAX request to the server:

```
$('#save').click(function() {
    $.post('/event', function(response) { console.log(reposne) })
});
```

On the server you should add a route that will handle your AJAX request, and inside this route you can save your model:

```
router.post('/event', function(req, res) {
  var ev = new Event({ date: "a6_13_2016", time: 900, description:"Fencing"});
    ev.save(function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log("Success!")
    })
});
```

Please note that you don't need the 3rd param next in your rotues. It is used only in middlewares

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that line

```
var Event = require('../models/Events.js');
```

has the correct path?

You are creating an ev object from Event function and it seems that ev is undefined, judging from the error description.

If your Event file is not properly loaded you will not have access to .save function.